# Show flot timeline ticks on both top and bottom

Tags: flot

I have been using flot for a couple days and its great, but I can't seem to find an answer to this:

Is it possible to display the xaxis/timeline ticks on both the top and bottom of my chart?

My chart has a large height and it's hard for the user to know which date the points are on when scrolling away from the top where the time ticks are currently displayed.

I searched around and all I found was this one issue on github which appears to have never been implemented:
https://github.com/flot/flot/issues/1040

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that with the default options, but it is possible with a workaround:

- Duplicate your data series, use the normal options plus `xaxis: 1` for the first one while making the second one invisble with this options:

  ```
  points: {
      show: false
  },
  lines: {
      show: false
  },
  xaxis: 2
  ```
- Use this options for the x axes:

  ```
  xaxes: [{
      position: "top"
  }, {
      position: "bottom",
      alignTicksWithAxis: 1
  }],
  ```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b5k2d9r2/) for a full example.

Comment: For an alternative solution see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23996806/2610249